# Where is mathematica help notebook?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

I apologize that this isn't a question on how to use Mathematica, but rather where the documentation lies inside the applications folder.

During a drag and drop, I happened to drag the Mathematica symbol on the help window (on a Mac) onto the desktop, which just ended up dragging the help file onto the desktop. Now, I don't know where in the applications folder folder that file belongs (file name: `Mathematica.nb`) so that I can place it back and my help won't start because the file isn't where it is looking. My best guess is somewhere in `/Applications/Mathematica/Documentation/`, but theres tonnes of folders in there. Could someone check in their folder and let me know where this file belongs (again, I'm on a Mac)?

Comment: Finder has undo, in case this happens again.

Comment: @Timo: yes, however, I hadn't noticed that this had happened. Since I had my help already open, it didn't matter. I noticed only when i opened mma after the next restart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In[70]:= FileNames["Mathematica.nb", $InstallationDirectory, Infinity]

Out[70]= {"C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\8.0.1\\Documentation\\English\\System\\Guides\\\
Mathematica.nb", "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\8.0.1\\Documentation\\English\\System\\\
ReferencePages\\Programs\\Mathematica.nb"}
```

You want the first one, in Documentation/English/System/Guides.

Comment: Yes.

On a Mac, the output will look a little different.

Of course, in Finder, you ctrl-Click on `Mathematica.app` to see the file structure.

`{"/Applications/Mathematica.app/Documentation/English/System/Guides/\
Mathematica.nb", \
"/Applications/Mathematica.app/Documentation/English/System/\
ReferencePages/Programs/Mathematica.nb"}`